# why do values returned by std::end() change as the container changes, but not with std::begin()?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a `std::list` that I am inserting items into, and I have a `std::unordered_map` where I want to store iterators to the elements inserted into the `std::list` (I am implementing a LRU cache). The following code does not give me the output I expect:

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::list<int> l;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::iterator> listItems;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        l.push_back(i);
        listItems[i] = std::end(l);
    }
        

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << *(listItems[i]) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

The output here is `5 5 5 5 5` - the output I want/expect is `0 1 2 3 4`. I would have guessed looking at this code that `std::end` returns an iterator to the last element of the list, which is copied into listItems[i], but this is clearly not what is happening. I am confused why adding items to the list affects the result of earlier calls to `std::end`

However, if I change the first loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    l.push_front(i);
    listItems[i] = std::begin(l);
}
```

I get the output I expect - `0 1 2 3 4`. So what is the difference here between `push_front` and `push_back`, and `std::begin` and `std::end`

Comment: std::end returns an iterator to one past the end of the container. You are never suppose to dereference it. `*(listItems[i])` is undefined behavior.

Comment: For that matter either `push_back` or `push_front` may invalidate **all** the previously assigned iterators, so your whole data structure is problematic.

Comment: @MarkRansom could you expand on this? under what conditions could this happen?

Comment: @AlexArmbruster There is a nice summary of when iterators are invalidated at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation). (Despite that earlier comment, neither `push_back()` nor `push_front()` invalidate any iterators of a `std::list`. It's `vector`, `deque`, `unordered_set` and `unordered_multiset` whose iterators can be invalidated by insertion.)

Comment: @AlexArmbruster my mistake.  I didn't notice that you were using `std::list` and not `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the last element's iterator, it can be achieved by: `std::prev(std::end(l))`. Your code stored the end iterator and dereference it, it's UB.

And the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) of `std::list::end`:

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
> container, This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it
> results in undefined behavior.

For `std::begin`, we get the iterator to the first element of the container, it's safe the deference it and gets the corresponding element.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
  std::list<int> l;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>::iterator> listItems;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    l.push_back(i);
    listItems[i] = std::prev(std::end(l));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) std::cout << *(listItems[i]) << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fYTPGh39e)

Comment: It's safe *until* the `push_back` which invalidates all the iterators.  Sometimes it won't invalidate them so it might *look* like it's working, but it's not.

Comment: @MarkRansom Could you please elaborate why `push_back` on `std::list` caused an iterator to invalidate?

Comment: @MarkRansom I have double-checked with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004916/1292791), I think you are wrong here.

Comment: @MarkRansom You're confusing `std::list` with `std::vector`.

Comment: Node based containers such as `std::list` do not suffer pointer invalidation when adding or removing _other_ elements.  I do not see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis `back()` gives you an element but not an iterator, which is what OP wants.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel you're too fast.  I literally fixed that in 12 seconds after writing it and you already commented. :)

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel you're right.  I hang my head in shame.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin sorry, I was thinking of `std::vector`.  `std::list` does *not* have the problem I was pointing out.